# .Net open source clustering products? ... like Terracotta

Tags: c#, .net, load-balancing, cluster-computing

Does .Net have any open source clustering products like terracotta (http://www.terracotta.org/)?

Comment: are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: [Carrot2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot2) is an "open source search results clustering engine" that has a C# API: http://project.carrot2.org/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they have anything exactly like Terracotta... but there is [velocity](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/) on the cards from MS(who knows when) as well as [MEMCache](http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/)(heard bad things) has a port to .NET now and also [indeXus.Net](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/)